# Add pagination for a pdfdocument ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, pagination, pdfkit

I have created a pdf document and displayed it in a PDFView using PDFKit.Is there any direct way to show the pages in the document as pagination.

Comment: Is there any pods available which gives the document view with pagination?

Comment: Im unaware of any pods.  I would either put all PDF's into one document.  Or use a UITableView / UICollectionView to display the PDF's by page.

Comment: I got it .you can use thumbnailView of PDFKit to do this.

Answer (score 5):

YEs, they have a built in method called `usePageViewController(enable:options:)` you can use this on your `PDFView` object in the `viewDidAppear` and it will show you it in a UIPageViewController.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_animated: Bool) {
     pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
}
```